# How to hold the control in angularJS or JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have many services which gives data but takes time so is there a way to hold the control in angularJS or JQuery which will be executed once the other code will be finish.

Ex:

```
function fun1(){
  // many functions get data
}

function fun2(){
  // many functions get data
}

function fun3(){
 // here I want to call fun1() 
 //once fun1() is executed then only call fun2() 
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this in the angularJS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on *how* the "many functions get data". Generally you'd pass `fun2` as a callback to `fun1()` or use promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promises or $q

See here for more details https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

```
function fun1(){
   var deferred = $q.defer();

  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');

    if (okToGreet(name)) {
      deferred.resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
    } else {
      deferred.reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
    }
  }, 1000);

  return deferred.promise;
}

function fun2(){
  // many functions get data
}

function fun3(){
  // here I want to call fun1() 
  //once fun1() is executed then only call fun2() 

  var promise = fun1();

  promise.then(function() {
    //called if fun1 return successfully
    fun2();
  }, function(reason) {
       alert('Failed: ' + reason);
  }, function(update) {
     alert('Got notification: ' + update);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Callbacks would work:

```
function fun1(cb) {
   // do stuff
   cb();
}

function fun2() {
   // do stuff
}

function fun3() {
  fun1(fun2);
}
```

Or go with promises as outlined in the other answer.

Comment: The fun1 and fun2 are running asynchronously, so if I call fun1 & then fun2 the from then the fun2 gets executed before the fun1

Comment: Ah, OK, was not clear. Then either go with callbacks or promises.

Comment: about using promise, in the fun1() there are already three promises which gets data from API and SET that data to Scope and this Scope data is used in fun2() to perform some operations, how do use Callback?

Comment: I outlined in the answer how to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop the code flow in javascript using any framework out there. What you are refering to is async code flow Which as referred by folks below can be done by promises or callbacks only

Comment: about using promise, in the fun1() there are already three promises which gets data from 3 API call where promise is used and Set that data to Scope and this Scope data is used in fun2() to perform some operations, how do use Callback?